# Ionic2 ngOnInIt on navigation pop

Tags: ionic2

I have two pages: *VideoPage* and *ExerciseListPage*. I am in VideoPage and when I do `this.navCtrl.pop()`I come back to ExerciseListPage.

When I come back to ExerciseListPage page I want to fire `ngOnInIt()`method present on that page (because I do some initialization there and the values that are changed from my VideoPage now need to reflect on ExerciseListPage).

I tried following: In my VideoPage:

```
this.events.publish('reloadList');
this.navCtrl.pop();
```

And in ExerciseListPage controller:

```
this.events.subscribe('reloadList',() => {
            this.navCtrl.pop();
            this.navCtrl.push(ExerciseListPage);

        });
```

This did not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually simple, I just fired ngOnInIt again like following:

```
this.events.subscribe('reloadList',() => {
 this.ngOnInit();
});
```